# getPost() on array element in plugin

Tags: plugins

I'm trying to get data submitted from a form using `craft()->request->getPost()`, but I'm not sure what to do when the form name is an array element.

For example, I have a form with:

```html
<label for="notes">Notes</label>
<textarea rows="6" id="notes" name="fields[notes]"></textarea>
```

and want to use:

```php
craft()->request->getPost('fields[notes]');
```

but when I do this I don't get any data from the form, and I'm not sure what to put in `getPost()` to let it know its an array.

It will work fine if I change the name to "notes" and use `getPost('notes')`, but I'd like to be able to get it working with the array.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use dot notation:

```php
craft()->request->getPost('fields.notes');
```

Comment: nice answer selvin!

Comment: Thanks! this is just what I needed.  I'm doing something similar to this [ContactForm](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ContactForm) example, and trying to do the same thing to get a file, should `\CUploadedFile::getInstanceByName('fields.file')` work the same way? This part is still not working for me and I'm not sure if it is supposed to work the same way or if there is some other error in my code.

Comment: I got the file working using `getInstanceByName('fields[emp_resume]');` which is what wouldn't work before.  I am confused why it works here but not in the other case, and how I'm supposed to remember which way will work?

Comment: In both instances, you're working with an associative array (`$_POST`, `$_FILES`) but the abstraction to find nested keys is implemented differently in for each purpose. For example, when you do `craft()->request->getPost('fields.notes)` you're saying "Craft, look at the `$_POST` array and find the passed in (dot notated) string" so Craft will check if there is a `files` key and then check if a `notes` key exist within the `files` keys. When you use `\CUploadedFile::getInstanceByName('fields[file]`)` Yii will look for what you want in the `$_FILES` array not the `$_POST` array.

Comment: All of that to say that dot notation (`fields.notes`) and bracket notation (`fields[file`) are both syntactic sugar added on top of arrays. You could easily grab the first key from both and then look for the nested key within them in vanilla PHP or use the `isset()` technique.

<!-- language: lang-php -->

    $fields = isset($_POST['fields']['notes']) ? $_POST['fields']['notes'] : false;

    $files = isset($_FILES['fields']['file']) ? $_FILES['fields']['file'] : false;

    if ($notes) { // You have notes... }
    if ($files) { // You have files... }

Answer (score 1):

Note:

There might be cases where you want to check whether the post data is an actual array before using it, this isn't possible with the dot notation:

```php
$data = craft()->request->getPost('fields');

if (is_array($data)) {
    //Do stuff...
}
else {
    //Do stuff...
}
```

For example the [ContactForm](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ContactForm) plugin allows you to specify [additional body fields](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ContactForm#adding-additional-fields) that way:

```html
One message field:    
<input id="msg" type="text" name="message" value="">

Multiple message fields:
<input id="phone" type="text" name="message[phone]" value="">
<input id="name" type="text" name="message[name]" value="">
```

.

Also like Selvin noted in the comments, you might want to check whether the field is actually set to prevent errors.

Comment: This is not safer than trying to access `fields.notes` directly and in fact, if you do this, you have a greater chance of running into `undefined index` because "notes" may not exist in the `$data` array.

Comment: You're right, I clarified my answer.